# Wrong TLS with RESTDataSource from Apollo and HttpsProxyAgent

Tags: node.js, proxy, openssl, apollo, http-proxy

I'm setting up a link between my Apollo Server (Node) and a REST API. My endpoint is `https://app.myproject.local/api/v1` and is served  via Hotel through a Pacfile available from `http://localhost:2000/proxy.pac`.

In reality this endpoint is also available from `http://localhost:4000/api/v1` but I want to access it with Hotel.

I figured `app.myproject.local` wasn't resolved if I tried to access it directly in the node application, so I should go through `HttpsProxyAgent` and get it  from there.

```
import { RESTDataSource } from 'apollo-datasource-rest'
import HttpsProxyAgent from 'https-proxy-agent'
import { restConfig } from '../config/restConfig'

export class RestAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.baseURL = restConfig.endpoint
  }

  public willSendRequest(request: any) {
    request.agent = new HttpsProxyAgent({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 2000,
      secureProxy: false,
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    })
  }

  public async test() {
    return this.get('/status')
  }
}
```

Despite having `rejectUnauthorized` it throws an error

```
(node:40593) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://app.myproject.local/api/v1/organizations/current failed, reason: write EPROTO 4474312128:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:
```

When I try to do the same kind of fetch with cURL it does work with

```
curl --insecure --proxy http://localhost:2000/proxy.pac https://app.myproject.local/api/v1/status
```

It may be a misunderstanding from my part but I thought `rejectUnauthorized` would bypass this SSL certificate problem. I'm actually  using this in development environment so it does not matter so much, in production I won't need to  go through all this.

I'm using the documentation of https://node.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/tls/#tlsconnectport-host-options-callback to help me pass arguments to `HttpsProxyAgent`

Answer (score 1):

```
const https = require('https')

...
  willSendRequest(request) { 
    request.agent = new https.Agent({ rejectUnauthorized: false })
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

proxy.pac is a file that tells a web browser which proxy to use for a given request. You generally don't use it as a proxy itself.